# Efficient use of Construction Robots

Tags: factorio

I often find myself constructing things using blueprints because it's so much easier than laying multiple things by hand. I was recently doing this at a remote mine site, that I had connected via Roboports to my main base, because I wanted to ensure that any damage would be automatically repaired by construction robots using the repair packs that I requested for the roboports.

However I noticed that as I was stamping down my blueprints, my personal robot swarm was only doing one trip between me and the planned items on the ground, and leaving the rest to be laboriously brought from my base which takes between two to three minutes. It would have been much faster if my personal robots did the construction.

From now on, I'm planning to leave connecting the roboport network till after construction, but it seems like a waste, when they could be spending the time that I'm constructing, transporting the decent amount of repair packs that they will require.

Is there any way to tweak the logic that determines which robots are chosen for a construction task or do I just have to not connect up the network till I'm done?

Comment: Hmm. I know of a mod that does the *opposite* of what you want, I think, but maybe not one that does precisely what you’re looking for.

Comment: I flat out stopped using Construction bots in my Logistics network because of that. I opted instead to manually clear out the biters in or near pollution range, so i almost never need repairs which is the only thing i would want non personal roboport construction bots for. when i get attacked, that just means its time to head up there ( repair damage) and take out a new enemy base.

Comment: In the next version of Factorio, 2.0, this will be significantly improved. Robots will have a queue of tasks rather than just one at a time, and they'll have a metric for arrival time, so that robots can be smarter about whether it makes sense for them to take on a task. Full details are here: [Friday Facts #374 - Smarter robots](https://factorio.com/blog/post/fff-374)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually there is no way. The following workaround should help:

- place a roboport with construction robots in the target area (**dont connect** the port)
- place a yellow chest including all blueprint parts next to the port
- use blueprint
- after completition fill the gap of roboports to connect the robonetwork to your main factory

This way they will construct while you can place belts, or do whatever you want.

It's not as perfect as you'd like to have it, but this is the closest possibility to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you had more personal roboports, the limit of robots would increase. This would increase the upper limit of things possible to build by the robots in one run.

I have to agree, that the logic here is far from perfect and the planner should be smarter here, as it is obviously stupid to send the robots from FAR FAR away, when waiting just 1 more second allows you to use the nearby robot.